# two pages on one and exact crop marks

Tags: pdfpages, printing, crop

the page size of my document is A5 and has about 100 pages.

For printing I need to put two pages on one in A4 and rearrange them in a specific way due to my thumb index at eachside of the page.

That's the code I got so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{forloop}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\newcounter{i}
\newcounter{p}
\newcounter{pp}
\newcounter{ppp}
\newcounter{pppp}

\forloop{i}{1}{\value{i} < 34}{%
\setcounter{p}{\thei*4+2}
\setcounter{pp}{\thei*4-1}
\setcounter{ppp}{\thei*4}
\setcounter{pppp}{\thei*4+1}

\includepdfmerge[nup=1x2, landscape]{file.pdf, \thep,\thepp,\theppp,\thepppp}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to add crop marks like this:

[image]

3mm margin for printing area and 3mm crop marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had finally an idea over night and solved it:

```
\documentclass[twoside,landscape]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=6mm, left=6mm, right=0mm, bottom=0mm}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
opacity=1,
angle=0,
color=black,
contents={%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[thick] ($(current page.north west)+(0mm,-9mm)$) -- ++(\paperwidth,0mm); %o
  \draw[thick] ($(current page.south west)+(0mm,9mm)$) -- ++(\paperwidth,0mm); %u
  \draw[thick] ($(current page.north east)+(-9mm,0mm)$) -- ++(0,-\paperheight); %r
  \draw[thick] ($(current page.north west)+(9mm,0mm)$) -- ++(0,-\paperheight); %l
  \draw[thick] ($(current page.north)+(0mm,0mm)$) -- ++(0,-\paperheight); %m
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}

\newcommand{\ing}[1]{\includegraphics[width=(\textwidth-6mm)/2,height=\textheight-6mm,page=#1]{empty}}

\newcommand{\pdf}[4]{
\hspace*{-11pt}%
\ing{\numexpr#1\relax}%
\ing{\numexpr#2\relax}%
\clearpage%
\hspace*{6pt}%
\ing{\numexpr#3\relax}%
\ing{\numexpr#4\relax}%
\clearpage%
}

\pagestyle{plain}
\newcounter{i}
\begin{document}

%%% Cover
\pdf{1}{3}{3}{3}

%%% Inhalt
\forloop{i}{1}{\value{i} < 34}{%
\pdf{\thei*4+2}{\thei*4-1}{\thei*4}{\thei*4+1}
}

%%% letzte 3 Seiten
\pdf{3}{137}{138}{139}

\null\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the option `a5paper` you can use any setting for your paper dimension. The package `crop` allows several crop marks, see documentation (run `texdoc crop`),. You can adopt this solution for using `pdfpages` and two on one.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a5paper}
\usepackage[center,a4,cross]{crop}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
```

\end{document}

[image]

Comment: that didn't answer my question. I didn't want to have such big crop marks. Just 3mm like in my solution; besides it doesn't have x-shaped marks